# Error in Windows 8 phone app code for FIle Picker

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using PhoneApp4.Resources;
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using Windows.Storage.Pickers;
using Windows.Storage.FileProperties;
using System.IO;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;

namespace PhoneApp4
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowserTask wbt = new WebBrowserTask();
        wbt.Uri = new Uri("http://www.facebook.com", UriKind.Absolute);
        wbt.Show();
    }

    private void Play_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        medias.Play();

    }

    private void Pause_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        medias.Pause();

    }

    private void Stop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        medias.Stop();
    }



        private async void Browse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();

     //     openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;

            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");

            var file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

            var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
             stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);


  if (null != file)
 {
                medias.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);


}
}
}
}
```

The code is of audio player and I want to pick files from storage.
In above code following code generates error

```
if (null != file){  medias.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType); }
```

Error is:- No overload for method 'SetSource' takes 2 arguments.
can anyone help me with that? Plzz
And also if any other mistake let me know about that.

Comment: What is the `medias`' type? Also, where did you get that code in the first place?

Comment: medias is name of media element i have used.
Visit this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh871377.aspx

Comment: Did you take a look at `MediaElement.SetSource` documentation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.setsource%28v=vs.95%29.aspx It appears that there is no method with tho arguments, why would you want to pass two arguments if that function doesn't exist

Comment: Also note that your link is for Windows 8 and you are asking for Windows **Phone** 8.

Comment: can you provide me the link to verify my code for Windows Phone 8?

Comment: For what? Using media element? Well, just pass the stream to it and you are done. Also, you cannot use file picker on Windows Phone 8.

Answer (score 3):

As [MSDN for FileOpenPicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207847) says:

> Windows Phone 8
>   This API is supported in native apps only.

**EDIT**
As ToniPetrina says there can be more issues regarding your code. I've pointed the one that will probably make impossible to do what you want. As it it also [mentioned here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/7e4492dc-d8f3-4dc5-8055-625352aaa8b6/fileopenpicker-class-on-wp8?forum=wpdevelop):

> The FileOpenPicker in WP8 is simply a Windows Runtime wrapper over the same photo library functionality that's accessible from the managed PhotoChooserTask. We do not currently support choosing files other than photos or choosing files from other Store apps.

AFAIK it's very hard to copy files from MediaLibrary to IsolatedStorage. And I also would be grateful if someone had showed how to do it.

Comment: That is not his (only) problem.

Comment: @ToniPetrina You are right, there are probably more issues, I've pointed the one that makes it impossible (AFAIK) to do what OP wants.